# Re-creating RDS instance from snapshot with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create a RDS instance with CloudFormation and keep a snapshot when the stack is deleted. According to AWS, I can do that by setting `DeletionPolicy: Snapshot` in my Cloudformation template.

When I create a stack from the same template I want to use the snapshot. I can do that with `DBSnapshotIdentifier`.

I need a CloudFormation template that will:

1. Execute normally the first time the RDS instance is created (and there is no snapshot available), and:
2. Update the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` every time the stack gets deleted

Comment: Please provide CFN template demonstrating your issue and allowing for its reproduction. Otherwise, its not clear what is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> works when the RDS instance is created for the very first time and
> there no snapshot available?

No, it doesn't work. DBSnapshotIdentifier requires a snapshot ARN, that you won't have before the creation of the snapshot.

> updates the DBSnapshotIdentifier every time the stack gets deleted?

The best solution here, in a Cfn template, would be to have a parameter to receive the snapshot ARN.

Reference:

- [DBSnapshotIdentifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier)
- [AWS::RDS::DBInstance Return Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#aws-resource-rds-dbinstance-return-values)